# Cannot enable feature with feature receiver via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, feature-activation

I have a problem where I can enable a feature from the UI and code in FeatureActivated method works as expected. However, if I try to enable the feature via powershell as a scripted deployment, the feature is activated but the code in FeatureActivated method is not executed.

I am running the Powershell as Admin.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Praveen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have some kind of threading issue here. Standard PowerShell runs each pipeline/line on different threads while the SharePoint PowerShell console runs all in the same thread. 
Try starting a std PowerShell console and write

```
$Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
```

And then run your script again and report back.

Also make sure that you do not have any references to SPContext in your receivers...

Comment: +1 for being precise!

Comment: Hi Wictor

it worked from the Std PowerShell Console when I changed $Host.Runspace.ThreadOptions from "Default" to "ReuseThread"

Thanks

Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I got this working now.

The code in FeatureActivated was not executing when I used the General PowerShell command window even when running with Admin rights.

However, the code executed fine when I used “SharePoint 2010 Management Shell”.

Praveen

Comment: SP management shell adds the SharePoint cmdlets as it loads up. Also before running any scripted deployment make sure that you have the necessary permissions assigning your user Shell admin role: Add-SPShellAdmin [-UserName] <String>  [-database <SPDatabasePipeBind>] . Read more on my blog http://andersrask.spoint.me/2010/09/26/how-to-add-a-user-to-the-sharepoint_shell_access-role-on-a-content-database/

Answer (score 0):

Use Sharepoint Management shell to run Powershell scripts. We have faced the same issue and got the solution by using Sharepoint Management shell which automatically adds Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell dll as reference.